# Showing subset of a coordinate chart belongs to atlas

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

The following is a problem from Tu's book on manifolds

> Let $\{(U_\alpha), \phi_\alpha)\}$ be the maximal atlas on a manifold $M$. For any open set $U$ in $M$ and a point $p \in U$, prove the existence of a coordinate open set $U_\alpha$ such that $p \in U_\alpha \subset U$.

My proof:
Since $p \in M$, there is some coordinate chart $U_\beta \ni p$ with corresponding coordinate map $\phi_\beta$. Now define $U_\alpha = U_\beta \cap U$ with coordinate map $\phi_\alpha = \phi_\beta|_{U_\alpha}$, thus $(U_\alpha, \phi_\alpha)$ is a coordinate chart with $p \in U_\alpha \subset U$, as desired.

It remains to show that this coordinate chart belongs to $M$. Suppose $(U_\gamma, \phi_\gamma)$ is any coordinate chart in $M$. We would like to show that the maps
$$\phi_\gamma \circ \phi_\alpha^{-1}: \phi_\alpha (U_\alpha \cap U_\gamma) \rightarrow \phi_\gamma(U_\alpha \cap U_\gamma), \quad \phi_\alpha \circ \phi_\gamma^{-1}: \phi_\gamma (U_\alpha \cap U_\gamma) \rightarrow \phi_\alpha(U_\alpha \cap U_\gamma) \tag{1}$$
are both smooth. This is where I am getting stuck. I am thinking of using the fact that $(U_\beta, \phi_\beta)$ is compatible with $(U_\gamma, \phi_\gamma)$, as both belong to the same atlas, and since the maps in (1) are just restrictions of $\beta$ then we can conclude that both transition maps are also smooth. However, making this argument rigorous is causing me some trouble.

Comment: Your argument seems rigorous to me! You can add that $\phi_{\gamma}\circ \phi_{\alpha}^{-1} = \phi_{\gamma}\circ \phi_{\beta}^{-1}|_{\phi_{\beta}(U_\alpha\cap U_{\gamma})}$, but your argument is already fine

Comment: @Didier Awesome, thank you!